# Estimate null hypothesis for correlation of linear combinations of variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, covariance, correlation

**Setting up the problem**

Suppose I have a variable $x$ of length $n$ and I have another $p$ variables $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_p$, where $y_i$ is also of length $n$.

Based on the y's, I can make a linear combination to estimate $x$. Let $\hat{x}$ be the best linear fit:
$\hat{x} = a_1 y_1 + a_2 y_2 + \dots + a_p y_p $

I can now calculate the correlation between $\hat{x}$ and $x$.

**The question:**

My question is how do I calculate whether this correlation I get can be explained by the null hypothesis in this case.

**My own insights**

The answer to this question will for sure depend on the size of $n$ and $p$ if $p>n$ then I would expect a correlation of 1 always since even random variables should be able to fit exactly in that case, but for the more interesting case of $n > p$ how would I go about estimating this?

**Unsatisfactory solution**

My own idea for a solution would be to do a permutation test as detailed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Inference , but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution.

**Summary**

In summary, I'm looking for the probability that a linear combination of random variables has a correlation of $c$ or higher with another another random variable, given $p$ variables and a sample size of $n$.

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is 
`<X>`, and you're wondering if `<Y>` is a good way to go 
about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As 
it is written right now, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hmm I don't quite agree that this is an XY problem. What I am saying is that I would like to solve problem X, and I know one possible solution to that problem, but I know that my solution isn't the best and would like to know if anyone else knows a better solution. I could of course have removed the part about the solution I already know about, but then I run into the risk of someone else suggestion to solve it in that way.

Comment: Then please edit the post to tell us the background of the problem in more practical terms!

Comment: I just looked at my question again and I really don't see what exactly it is you suggest I add to this question. I feel like the practical background is already there. (The first 5 lines of text\formulas) and the question I want answered follows immediately afterwards. After that I tell my own insights about the problem followed by my own unsatisfactory solution to the problem. Finally I summarize the problem in the final paragraph. So please enlighten me as to exactly which part of this is unclear or lacking the necessary details? 

I guess I can make a clearer separation of these concepts

Comment: I just made the separation clearer, does that help?